# How to draw an 'X' over the number a list item <li> of an unordered list <ul> contains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having this issue crossing out numbers with jquery, javascript, and css. The way I have code set up is to display a group of numbers and disable/make transparent the number of a color the user selects. Where I'm stuck is overlaying an 'X' over the number when a user selects this number and it doesn't already exists in an array in local storage. So far I've tried z-index, css content of 'X', and was close on drawing a canvas but couldn't quite get it right.

I have list items like such:

```
<li id="red_2" class="redLI" onclick="selectNumForScore(this.id)">2</li>
<li id="red_3" class="redLI" onclick="selectNumForScore(this.id)">3</li>
<li id="yellow_2" class="yellowLI" onclick="selectNumForScore(this.id)">2</li>
<li id="yellow_3" class="yellowLI" onclick="selectNumForScore(this.id)">3</li>
```

...and it's not proper Pascal casing but works for this instance. In the onclick() event of each list item I check if the selection exists already. If it doesn't I'd simply like to draw an 'X' or place one over the number in that list item. Is this possible with the route I've gone in jquery, javascript and/or CSS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Pseudo-element

Comment: I don't really see anything that's going to help me overlay. This is the functionality I'm going for. I could never get this X to draw w/o it making the <li> larger, though.

https://jsfiddle.net/wintermute84/Ln2L3502/

Comment: [Ofcourse not](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv44365w/) ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't toggling the class with js. Thanks for the example!